# Run both TestUnit and RSpec when using rake

Tags: rspec, rake, testunit, rakefile

I started my project using TestUnit but now i'm looking to use RSpec instead.
To avoid re writing all the tests, it will be usefull if i could cohabit both of them when i'm launching rake.

Below my Rakefile:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
MyApp::Application.load_tasks
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Given normal usage, you shouldn't have any problems running `rake spec test` since `spec` and `test` are in separate folders. No modification of rakefile needed

Comment: **rake spec test** start just testUnit and not Rspec tests. More than that the command **rake test_spec.rb** doesn't works: **Don't know how to build task 'test_spec.rb'**